# Your considerations for loading process of your site

Tags: design-patterns

What do you care most in the **loading process** of your site

Statistical Data ,Performance , ...

We know that always we need to make a *balance* between **Quality & performance** ,

so for you as an architect-developer of a site , Which things do you consider
for the loading process of your site , What do you care most ?
I like to hear your ideas , and any details is much appreciated if possible

*At the time* that a new user or a known user visit your site what will happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for giving your opinions ,

*Mine* , I prefer always to see my work as a grown-up project when I have more clients and more data transactions , I will need more security and each millisecond counts , and I think performance is something that we can't omit , I think we need to consider them in the beginning phase of our project .

*But this is a question that I think is hard to answer :*

Gaining how much Information should be enough when a user visits a page of our site ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing to note is that as bandwidth increases, loading times are becoming less and less important, and as browsers and computer speeds skyrocket, performance is even less important.

**I am not saying that you should write slow code**, but rather that quality and graphics are very important. (eg. just recently Flash has become fast enough to reasonably handle 3d, and so despite the relative slowness of it, these type of interfaces have become acceptable)

I would **highly** recommend that if you do not have a background in graphic design, that you find someone who does to help you.

Also, Mockups, Mockups, Mockups.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't care about the loading process until I see that it causes trouble.

In most cases my opinion is that you should always prioritize quality over performance (to use your terms). If performance becomes a problem at some point, then you can go optimize. It's a simple case of cost-benefit.

But it always comes down to what kind of site you're designing. Obviously, if you have lots of heavy database interaction you may as well start optimizing, caching, etc. from the beginning.